Who is the actress?
In the "Lord of the Elves" trailer, who is the actress at 31 seconds? Is she in any other movies or tv shows?


some one down-voted you for posting a question. you should know questions are not allowed on this site...

Lord of the Elves is also called Clash of the Empires. It stars Bai Ling, who is pictured in your image. More information can be found on the wikipedia page 

The actress is Bai Ling. Answer was found on Google Play. You may recognize her from her role as Miss East in Wild Wild West (1999), the Mysterious Woman in Sky Captain and The World of Tomorrow, or perhaps as Achara from the Lost episode, season 3 episode 9 titled Stranger in a Strange Land.

Google Play??! How the hell did you manage that?

@poepje, it's been a while since I posted the answer, but I believe I used Google's Search By Image tool and Google Play was the first result.
